# How to change font and set word wrap viewing for "find symbol search" result in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to set the font and be able to view in word wrap mode when viewing the results after making a search for a symbol (I often search for references of a method). I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I have this problem too... it shows the font in the old System font from Windows 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools -> Options  -> Environment  -> Fonts and Colors

Then choose what window to change in the “Show settings for” dropdown.

As far as I know, you can't change the wordwrap.

Comment: Sorry, but how can this be the correct answer when the "Find Symbol Results" window isn't in the dropdown list of windows on Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors?
I'd like to make the same adjustments but if the window I'm interested in changing isn't listed how can I make this change?

Comment: @Lou Perhaps JM10 was using VS 2008, where I can confirm it is an option (which, as you point out, doesn't necessarily help you or the OP).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the word wrap settings for the search windows go to Tools/Options/Text Editor/Plain Text and check the Word Wrap checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the word wrap using Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->Word wrap

Comment: To be specific, Plain Text only, since that is the setting that affects the Find Results window

Answer (score 0):

Note aside:

How to change the word wrap symbol's color,
aka...

**Change 'Visual glyph for word wrap' foreground color in Visual Studio 2015**

===

Main menu: "**Tools**" –> "**Options**"

'Options' window: Left-column: "**Environment**" –> "**Fonts and Colors**"

Right-pane heading: 'Display items:' -> 6th item down: "**Visible White Space**"

Change the '**Item foreground**' color, and click the bottom button "**OK**".

**You must restart Visual Studio to see the change.**

===

Note:

"Visible White Space" is the 6th item in the 'Display items:' list.

The item "Visible White Space", which is responsible for the foreground color change of the 'word wrap' glyph, is Not listed alphabetically, in the sense that it is Not at the very bottom of the list under 'View Definition Mark' as you might expect.

"Visible White Space" is the sixth-item. "Visible White Space" and the five items above it, comprise a separate set of alphabetized item at the top of the 'Display items:' list, and all of the other options that follow are themselves in a distinct alphabetical listing of their own. There is no demarcation between the two sets of alphabetized items, and there is no indication that the items #7, and beyond, will all be part of only one more group of alphabetized list items.